# How to create the automatic mass form submitter script to be used on the 3rd part websites, where I know their fields names-values?

Tags: javascript, ajax, bulk, form-submit

I need a script that can handle the following tasks.

Take user data from my database and fill in and submit / post data to forms
located on third part websites.: 
So I want to know if is it hard to create or do somebody knows if does exists some script for mass form submissions in PHP -Javascript-Ajax ?
I run Dancers & Hostess & Model jobs website, I would like to find some script which allows the girls automaticly submit to hundreds websites forms (other 3rd part model agencies) with their similar model application form info on my website previously specified,

- 1).Firstly the girls will fill out my
  agency portfolio very detailed form ,
  like this i will get all the model personal info
  from them ,
- 2) Secondly i would like to allow
  for example models to submit to
  100 and more other model agencies
  forms (I will find those websites before, and I
  will get their field names = values
  and thanks to some script would like 
  to connect them with every girl data 
  already created in my website to
  submit .

I would like to implement it to my wordpress website where the girls has their portfolios instead of my pages . 
I would like to offer this service especially to models , it should work like some directory submitters , The script knows names - values and fill it out itself, but I want it online - browser side, where the girls should only fill out captcha if there is and click the button "submit".After succesful submit it should offer other form to submit. 
                  I would be very happy if you know the answer or if you can redirect me to some article 
example website :[SEMI AUTOMATED LINK DIRECTORY][1]

[1]: http://www.onewaytextlink.com/links.php?type=free&pagenum=1"SEMI AUTOMATED LINK DIRECTORY"

Comment: So you want us to help with spamming?

Comment: Before You asked the question I responded below :
I would like to previusly ask the websites (Model Agencies) to use my script to fill out their forms on their websites. The websites will get respect to their agency relevant models which will get exact info what every agency needs and requires . I don't want to spam at all , but only help for example east european girls to find the job and agency in Australia and help them easily to fill out their forms like many SEMI AUTOMATED directory scripts do.

Comment: I only want TIME saving tool. In my website they will fill it in Czech , Russian etc and output will be in English in standards the other agencies wants . You can say it SPAM , I say : time saving HELP.There are many scripts if you google them but mostly all of them only link directory related - They are spammers too?
example here: 
http://demo.phpdirsubmit.com/admin/index.php?menu=overview

Comment: I need the same script like Link Directory Submitter but for Model Applications forms Submissions. I will ask the agencies before and I hope that in future they will ask me to be on my Agencie's list  to get more various types of models in their databases . So NO Spamming because they will agree or ask me to get the girls .

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but it ain't gonna work. Cross-domain ajax is forbidden. Although you can avoid this restriction more or less by [various techniques](http://ajaxpatterns.org/Cross-Domain_Proxy), many sites won't accept cross-site requests due to [security reasons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSRF).

Comment: I would like to previusly ask the websites (Model Agencies) to use my script to fill out their forms on their websites, I don't want to spam but only help for example east european girls to find the agency in Australia and help them easily to fill out their forms. In my website they will fill it in Czech , Russian etc and output will be in English in standards the other agencies wants . It is not necessary to have it in Ajax , Javascript .

Comment: So, you basically just want to create bunch of POST request to various locations? In PHP, you can use http_post_data() and http_post_fields() functions for that. http://fi2.php.net/manual/en/function.http-post-fields.php